# Doctrine2 entity creation error : "Could not find driver"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I'm learning how to use Doctrine in Symfony.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. My parameters.yml is configured with pdo_pgsql.

**My issue is when I give a shortcut name to my entity, 3 errors "could not find driver" appear.**

Here are two pictures of my terminal with the errors.
http://hpics.li/d6824c3
http://hpics.li/3ddd6c7
[Heberger image http://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_318085help1.png](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=318085help1.png)
I searched for an answer on the internet. In fact the issue should appear when the file php.ini is missing, but `php -i |grep php\.ini` shows the file exists.
[Heberger image http://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_233589help2.png](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=233589help2.png)

Here is the result of the command `php -i | grep pdo`
http://hpics.li/4589850
[Heberger image http://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_996595help3.png](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=996595help3.png)

You're free to help me to solve this "Could not find driver" issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you are missing pdo driver installed in your system. Depending on what db engine you configured in your `parameters.yml` it could be `pdo_pgsql` for instance.

Check what `php -i | grep pdo` command says - you should see your extension installed.

If not, you simply need to install it by using (example is for `postgresql`):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

`php -i | grep pdo` should show something like:

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini,
pdo_pgsql
```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. My `parameters.yml`  is configured with `pdo_pgsql`.  I'll edit my question to show what says the command `php -i | grep pdo`.

Comment: so you're missing ``php5-pgsql`` extension. I adjusted my answer to fit ``postgresql``

Comment: Indeed i'm missing php5-pgsql. I'll install it when i'll go home (the proxy blocks the donwload). Thank you @Tomasz

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the PDO and PDO_MYSQL extensions in your php.ini file.

On a windows server you can add the following lines in your php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

On a Linux server you can compile php with the following option

```
--with-pdo-mysql
```

In your php.ini, add the following lines

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Comment: Should I add them at the end of the `php.ini` file ? (I work with pgsql so i think it's `extension=pdo_pgsql.so`)

Comment: Uncomment the following in php.ini by removing the ";"

`;extension=php_pgsql.dll`

Comment: `extension=pdo_pgsql` is not found in my `php.ini`. As suggested @Tomasz I have to install pgsql.